# Need Kafka KRAFT SASL_PLAINTEXT

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl, kraft

I’m trying to get Kafka in kraft mode up n’ running with `SASL_PLAINTEXT`

I’ve got a functioning kafka broker/controller up n’ running locally, without `SASL` using this `servier.properties`

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
```

I’ve bound ports from the kafka docker container 9092 to 9092 on the host

```
kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --create --partitions 2 --replication-factor 1
```

Works like a charm, and I can produce and consume. Docker container logs looks good as well.

I need some users to handle ACL on our topics, so I thought it was easy to just replace all PLAINTEXT fields with SASL_PLAINTEXT, I was wrong!!

We handle encryption on another level, so `SASL_PLAINTEXT` is sufficient, we don't need `SASL_SSL`

This is the `config/kraft/sasl_server.properties` i've been trying out so far, with no luck.

I've constructed this properties file by reading this https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_plain.html

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9094
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9094
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
listener.name.controller.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="admin" \
  password="admin-secret" \
  user_admin="admin-secret";
plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
   username="admin" \
   password="admin-secret";
```

I’m getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaServer' or 'controller.KafkaServer' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
process.roles=$KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES
node.id=$KAFKA_NODE_ID
controller.quorum.voters=$KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS

listeners=BROKER://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
advertised.listeners=BROKER://:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=BROKER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT

inter.broker.listener.name=BROKER
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN

listener.name.broker.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="admin" \
    password="$KAFKA_ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
    user_admin="$KAFKA_ADMIN_PASSWORD";

listener.name.controller.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="admin" \
    password="$KAFKA_ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
    user_admin="$KAFKA_ADMIN_PASSWORD";
```

Here is a working configuration.

`sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol=PLAIN` was important.

Comment: PLAIN is what fixed my issue :)

Comment: The official kafka tutorial is missing the config `sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol`, so it is likely to be ignored by users. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-14369?jql=text%20~%20%22sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol%22